# Azure Used Vs Allocted Vs Maximum in elastic pool

Tags: azure-sql-database, maintenance-plan

I'm currently doing some cleanup on an Azure environment and just wanted to check calculations. I have about 55 Databases on an elastic server, which is currently sitting at 3.64TB of the maximum 4TB. Having a look at each of the databases within this pool, I can see that they have their own Used / Allocated / Maximum sizes. Each of these is ranging between 0.1% and 80% of their allocated 250GB. Is the allocated size of the elastic pool dependent on the maximum sizes of each of the databases within that elastic pool? IE if I took a database that is using 1GB of 250GB and reduced the maximum size of this database within the elastic pool from the default 250GB down to 20GB, would it have any positive/negative implications? If anyone can suggest any good resources for  azure environment maintenance plans it would be greatly appreciated as I'm coming from an AWS background.

Comment: This might be better asked on [su] or [sf].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your allotted area will immediately expand; you do not need to be concerned; this is typical. You'll see that occupied space is always close to available space. The key is when the total amount of allotted and utilised storage space approaches the maximum storage size.

If the database size reaches the maximum size, use the following statement to raise the maximum size or use Azure portal to alter the maximum size.

```
ALTER DATABASE AzureDB2 MODIFY (EDITION='STANDARD', MAXSIZE= 50 GB)
```

The database receives a certain amount of log space depending on the tier. When you specify the storage size in vCore, you are given a fixed amount of space for your logs. If you pick 1TB of storage, for example, 300GB is set aside for logs.